# how to count number of circles in Image using php

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

i have upload bellow image and that image have 5 circles. How can i count how many circle in such an image

[image]

Comment: You already know the number of circles, so just store the number with PHP or js next to the image and you're done.

Comment: I've got 3 possible options for you:
You can try the built-in PHP-function: `countNumberOfCirclesInThisImage('linktoimage.png');`
You can count them yourself and say `$number_of_circles = 5;`.
Or you can tell us what you already tried and how you would like the process to work.

Comment: @snaderss, there is no built in function called countNumberOfCirclesInThisImage

Answer (score 7):

Algorithm to detect circles or any mathematical shape: [Hough Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)

If you dont have any other shapes and your circles dont overlap/touch you could just loop through your image and every time you encounter a black pixel, you color all connected pixels with a color. When finished all your circles should have a different color. The number of different colors used is the number of circles.

For the last aproach you will need a binary picture (black & white pixels). Your example seems ok but if you have some kind of anti-aliasing going, you will need to threshold first. See [Wikipedia on Thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29)

If this whole area interests you, search for **computer vision**.